# Android: Prevent screen orientation change but still get notified about it

Tags: android, layout, configuration, orientation

I need to keep my Activity's layout in portrait mode but still get notified when the screen orientation changes in order to update my custom canvas. I have managed to prevent the Android OS from restarting my Activity and changing the layout when I change the screen orientation by putting these lines in my manifest XML:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

I'm also aware that I can change the screen orientation programatically by calling the method `setRequestedOrientation` from the Activity.

The problem is that the method `onConfigurationChanged` doesn't get called at all when I set the `screenOrientation` flag or call the method `setRequestedOrientation`. It does get called when I remove the flag from the manifest, but then the layout also gets updated which is not what I want.

Is there a way how to prevent the OS from changing the layouts but still be able to catch the configuration change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope [this class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html) will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Looks useful but wouldn't it consume too much CPU / battery when a sensor thread is running all the time? I don't need the exact orientation angle, just if it's portrait/landscape or their reverse counterparts.

Comment: You may have a point here. I didn't notice this class is providing an exact angle what seems indeed too much for what you intend to do. I'm sorry, but I don't know how else you could achieve this.

Comment: Since I've got no other answer and your solution can be used to solve my issue, although not precisely in the way I wanted, I'm accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had got the same problem. The thing which helped me, was to add one word in my mainfest XML:

> keyboardHidden

It should look like this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

For example in my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="pl.chris.mypicture"
   android:versionCode="1"
   android:versionName="1.0"
    >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
           android:name=".MyPictureActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
           android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I mean, how do you intercept the orientation mode? How do you know whether the device is in portrait mode or landscape? Thanks :)